# Unable to view Access Token and Refresh token in Spring Boot application integrated with Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-webflux

We have integrated keycloak login for a Spring Reactive based Spring boot application has follows.

Added Oauth client as maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Added below properties in properties file

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute
```

SecurityConfig  class is as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity()
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {


        http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/secured/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

This is working. 
We are using Spring security 5.7.7 version

But in browser I am able to see only "SESSION" Cookie as below.  I am unable to view Access token/ Refresh token. 
Please let me know how to view Access token and Refresh token.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests **from a browser to an OAuth2 client** aren't secured with OAuth2 access tokens, it is secured with sessions. Only requests **from OAuth2 clients to OAuth2 resource servers** are secured with access tokens.

If you want to see access the tokens, look into what is configured as an OAuth2 client. In your case, it is the Spring application (on the server), not the rendered template in the browser.

In Spring security Reactive stack, you might have a look at `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` or `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` to access the "authorized client" (which contain references to tokens).

If you have doubts about OAuth2 concepts and Spring configuration options, I suggest you have a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).